# Hacer zoom a gráfica en python

Tags: python, matplotlib

cómo hacer un zoom a la gráfica que muestro debajo. Lo que ocurre es que en la gráfica que tengo no se observa muy bien la curvatura de la gráfica y me gustaría que se viera más el cambio de concavidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me interesaría obtener algo más o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo para obtener la gráfica de arriba es:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
b = 0.0275 #constante
a = 1*10**(-5) #constante
r = np.arange(a, b, 1*10**(-7)) #Este es el rango y los pasos utilizados para graficar
E = 2000/(r*math.log(b/a)) #Evalúa cada punto de r en E
plt.plot(r,E,'blue',linewidth=1) #Hace la gráfica azul
#punto = plt.plot(0.003 , 84181.92724465077, 'ro')
texto1 = plt.text(0.010, 1.3*10**(7), r'$E = \frac{V_0}{r*\ln(\frac{b}{a})}$', fontsize=17)
plt.xlabel("Distancia (m)")
plt.ylabel("Campo E (V/m)")
plt.title("Campo eléctrico en función de la distancia")
plt.grid(True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mediante `plt.xlim()` puedes cambiar el rango que se muestra en el eje x. Por ejemplo:

```
plt.plot(r,E,'blue',linewidth=1) #Hace la gráfica azul
plt.xlim(0,0.001)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por supuesto también existe `plt.ylim()`. Y si uno de los límites es `None`, matplotlib intentará ajustarlo automáticamente.

En este ejemplo en particular, podríamos usar `None` en vez de 0, para que la gráfica no salga tan pegada a los ejes (pues matplotlib elegirá automáticamente valores negativos para estos límites para dejar un poco de margen por la izquierda y por debajo). Sin embargo, para el caso del eje X, debido a la diminuta escala en este eje, el algoritmo de matplotlib no elige un valor apropiado y puede ser mejor poner uno "a mano":

```
plt.plot(r,E,'blue',linewidth=1) #Hace la gráfica azul
plt.xlim(-0.0001, 0.001)
plt.ylim(None, 1e7)
```

En este caso la gráfica resultante es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un último detalle. La ecuación que querías poner en el centro de la figura, al haber cambiado el rango representado, ya no se ve (queda fuera), puesto que especificaste las coordenadas del texto usando el sistema de coordenadas de los datos. Para evitar estos problemas y que la ecuación siempre salga en el centro de la figura sin importar qué zona de los datos estés mostrando, puedes usar una transformación de coordenadas para que use el sistema de coordenadas de los ejes. En este sistema (0,0) es la esquina inferior izquierda y (1,1) la superior derecha siempre. Por tanto el centro es (0.5, 0.5). Si además ponemos el texto centrado en esa coordenada (con los parámetros `ha` y `va`), ya lo tenemos:

```
texto1 = plt.text(0.5, 0.5, r'$E = \frac{V_0}{r*\ln(\frac{b}{a})}$', 
                  ha="center", va="center",
                  fontsize=17, transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]